# force \groupplot to start from the bottom left corner

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Using \groupplot, subplots are generated starting from the upper left corner
as shown in the following illustration:
[image]

Is it possible to force it to start from the bottom left corner, i.e :

[image]

Here is a [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273791/how-to-skip-a-plot-in-groupplots-pgfplots) (As mentionned, mine hase 104 plots so it can't be considered as MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=4em}]
            \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

            \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
        \end{groupplot}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ofcourse, If i had only 3 or four plots, I can simply reorganize my document. But I have 104 subplots!

Comment: Hi ! Could you show us a MWE ?

Comment: This would take some modifications of the `groupplots` library I think. Rearranging things in Matlab isn't an option?

Comment: Unfortunatelly rearranging this in Matlab isn't possible as I don't have access to Matlab anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is to change some lines in the `groupplots` library. To avoid having a very lengthy answer I suggest editing a copy of the source file of that library and changing the lines in that copy.

Have a look at the comments in the following code for more details.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % copy the file
    %     `tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex'
    % to the folder of your main TeX file and rename it to
    %     `tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplotsMOD.code.tex'.
    % In that file replace some lines with the following code and remove
    % (only) the first comment sign on each of the lines.
    % (Please note that the given numbers are the *original* line numbers.
    %  To avoid confusion I suggest replacing them in reverse order.)
    %
    % 214
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%        % vertical order from top to bottom
    %%        at={($(\pgfplots@glob@TMPb.south)-(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep})$)},anchor=north,%
    %        % vertical order from bottom to top
    %        at={($(\pgfplots@glob@TMPb.north)+(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep})$)},anchor=south,%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 235
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%                \ifnum\pgfplots@row=\pgfplots@group@rows\relax%
    %                \ifnum\pgfplots@row=1%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 250
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%                        \ifnum\pgfplots@row=1 %
    %                        \ifnum\pgfplots@row=\pgfplots@group@rows\relax%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 317
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r1/.append style={xticklabel pos=upper}}%
    %              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@group@rows/.append style={xticklabel pos=upper}}%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 320
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
    %            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@rows
    %            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 329
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r\pgfplots@group@rows/.append style={xticklabel pos=lower}}%
    %              \pgfplots@glob@TMPa,/pgfplots/group/plot c\pgfplots@column r1/.append style={xticklabel pos=lower}}%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % 331-332
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%            \pgfplotsgroupplotsmath@decrease\pgfplots@group@rows
    %%            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} {%
    %            \foreach \pgfplots@row in {2,...,\pgfplots@group@rows} {%
    %% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplotsMOD}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=2 by 2,
                horizontal sep=4em,
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
            },
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
        ]
            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x^2 - x + 4};

            \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x^2 - x + 4};

            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x^2 - x + 4};
        \end{groupplot}
        \draw [thick,>=latex,->,red]
            (group c1r1.center) node {1.} -- (group c2r1.center) node {2.};
        \draw [thick,>=latex,->,red]
            (group c2r1.center) -- (group c1r2.center) node {3.};
        \draw [thick,>=latex,->,red]
            (group c1r2.center) -- (group c2r2.center) node {4.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks, this works. But the xticklabels are printed at the wrong subplots. I want to delete all xticklabels except at the bottom row. With your solution, they are printed at the top row. One more question: Can I have only three (or two) yticlabels per subplot? say for example, the minimum , average and maximum of ydata/ subplot?

Comment: It would have been nice, if you would have put __all__ your requirements __directly__ to the question and not asking for additional needs later on. Because that could end in a never ending story. Nevertheless, have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Regarding the `yticklabels`: This truly is a new/separate question which already was asked before [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301640/how-to-get-only-two-yticklabels-using-groupplot). So far it seems that nobody has a good idea for that. Maybe you could have at the [Feature Request Tracker of PGFPlots](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/) and add it there, if it shouldn't be in already.

Comment: You are right about the requirements, my bad. I just didn't notice it at the beginning. I am accepting your answer