# How to get only two `yticklabels` using `groupplots` library

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Having several subplots generated using `groupplots` library, I would like to automatically detect the data range in each subplot, and specify two `yticklabels` only (`ymin` and `ymax`). Because the data range in different subplots varies, I have to detect the minimum and maximum programmatically.

Comment: We're not good at reading minds, sorry. More information is needed.

Comment: @egreg, closers Really? I thinks it's quite clear what the OP wants.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Then provide an answer! ;-)

Comment: @egreg Understanding the question is not the same as being able to answer it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Then provide at least minimal example that demonstrates the question (if you think it is worth to invest your time in a question which the user abondoned 7 month ago).

Comment: I think that this needs a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to justify reopening.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would answer the question.  `pgfplots` needs to figure out the range of the data anyway, so the numbers are available in the macros `\pgfplots@data@ymin` and `\pgfplots@data@ymax`, just not in a "public" interface.

Borrowing an idea from Jake's answer to [Tufte like axis with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155194/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots/155212#155212), we can say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgfplotsdataymin\pgfplots@data@ymin
\newcommand\pgfplotsdataymax\pgfplots@data@ymax
\makeatother
```

and then add

```
ytick={\pgfplotsdataymin,\pgfplotsdataymax}
```

to the `groupplot` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgfplotsdataymin\pgfplots@data@ymin
\newcommand\pgfplotsdataymax\pgfplots@data@ymax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
   group size=1 by 3,
   x descriptions at=edge bottom},
 height=3cm,width=7cm,
 ytick={\pgfplotsdataymin,\pgfplotsdataymax}
]

\nextgroupplot
\addplot {rnd+1};

\nextgroupplot
\addplot {rnd*3+2};

\nextgroupplot
\addplot {rnd*6+7};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```